# Bind enum value to a property using style setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have the following code. Please look at Radio Button Style, I want to bind the value of the enum to a property in the ViewModel when the radio button is checked. I have property called SelectedWellType and I want to bind to it. But it says a binding cannot be set on Property of Type Property in Setter. Please help.

```
<RadioButton
            Name="IndividualWellsRadioButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
            KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True"
            Content="{StaticResource IndividualWells}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsIndividualWellAutoAnalysisPossible}">
            <RadioButton.IsChecked>
                <Binding
                    Converter="{StaticResource enumToBoolConverter}"
                    ConverterParameter="{x:Static dataDef:AutoAnalysisModes.IndividualWells}"
                    Path="AutoAnalysisMode" />
            </RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <RadioButton.Style>
                <Style
                    TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger
                            Property="IsChecked"
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter
                                Property="{Binding SelectedWellType}"
                                Value="{x:Static dataDef:AutoAnalysisModes.IndividualWells}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RadioButton.Style>
        </RadioButton>
```

Comment: Why don't you do that directly in the view-model? You don't need this indirection actually. Anyway, you cannot use a `Binding` in the `Property` of a `Setter`.

Comment: Oh in that case I will do it from the view model.